# Rails 3: Ruby 1.9.2: rake test: winshellTEST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, heroku, rake

I got an app from github called [Punchy](https://github.com/jgodse/Punchy), and I got it running on my local server (Windows Vista). It runs fine on Windows, and it runs fine on Heroku.

The environment is :

```
C:\Users\Jay\rapps\Punchy>rake about
(in C:/Users/Jay/rapps/Punchy)
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.2 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version          1.5.2
Rack version              1.2
Rails version             3.0.0
Active Record version     3.0.0
Action Pack version       3.0.0
Active Resource version   3.0.0
Action Mailer version     3.0.0
Active Support version    3.0.0
Application root          C:/Users/Jay/rapps/Punchy
Environment               development
```

However, I tried to run the tests by running

```
 > rake test
```

and it went bad. Here  is the result.

```
C:\Users\Jay\rapps\Punchy>rake test
(in C:/Users/Jay/rapps/Punchy)
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load': no such file to load --     winshellTEST
     (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load': no such file to load -- winshellTEST
 (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `load': no such file to load -- winshellTEST
 (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5:in `<main>'
Errors running test:units, test:functionals, test:integration!
```

Why does it run fine on my local machine, on Heroku, but the tests don't work? I appreciate any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Do you have any gem in your Gemfile that is only in the test group?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the tests from your fork and Mazondo's (2 out of 7 tests failed). I run them on osx, so the environment is quite different.

One thing I had to do to run the tests is to uncomment the line that declares sqlite3 as a dependency in Gemfile, and run the migrations.

Looks like the problem is the "integration" between rails/ruby and windows. It is interesting that the only hit in google for **winshellTEST** is your question.